# Ptolemy's theorem on a square circumscribed by a circle.

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Assume that the point P lies on the circle circumscribed by a square
> ABCD. Show that $PA^2+PC^2=PB^2+PD^2.$

[image]
[image]
[image]

**My take:**
Let us use the "chord-inequality" for a circle, which gives that :

$$PA+PC\leq AB+BC$$
$$PD+PB\leq BA+AD$$

Now, let us take the square on each side and obtain:

$$(PA+PC)^2\leq (AB+BC)^2$$
$$(PD+PB)^2\leq (BA+AD)^2$$

Since the circle circumscribes a square, where each side of the square is an equal chord to the circle, then $(AB+BC)^2=(BA+AD)^2$ and we can form the relation:

$$(PA+PC)^2=(PD+PB)^2$$

We can further confirm this result by Ptolemaios theorem. The theorem states that
$${\displaystyle AC\cdot BD=AB\cdot CD+BC\cdot AD}$$

Now,  the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ can be given by the triangle inequality on $PA+PC\geq AC$ and $BP+PD\geq BD$. Insert this for in the Ptolemaios theorem and obtain:

$${\displaystyle AC\cdot BD\leq (PA+PC)\cdot (CD+BC)=AB\cdot CD+BC\cdot AD}$$

However, assuming that the first proof is not enough, how can one connect the last equation by Ptomemaios theorem to the original form $PA^2+PC^2=PB^2+PD^2.$ ?

Any hints appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you see that by Thales the angles at P are right angles? Draw AC and BD and use Pythagoras for the resulting triangles.

Comment: Thank Gary, got it.